# Convert Latitude Longtitude to an Address in a map

Tags: javascript, php, html, geolocation

my code:
(i used ArcGIS for the map code https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_locate.html )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>OpenStreetMap</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.35/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #esri-map-container {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
      }
      #LocateButton {
      position: absolute;
      top: 95px;
      left: 20px;
      z-index: 50;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.35/"></script>
  <script>
    var map; 

    require([
      "esri/map", 
      "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, LocateButton)  
    {
      map = new Map("map", {
        center: [-56.049, 38.485],
        zoom: 3,
        basemap: "streets"
      });
            
      geoLocate = new LocateButton({
        map: map
      }, "LocateButton");
      geoLocate.startup();

      geoLocate.on('locate', (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
    });
  </script>

  </head>  
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map">
    <div id="LocateButton"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

So i get coordinates with:

```
geoLocate.on('locate', (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
```

and then i want to convert them into an address.
with the address i want to give them information about the city they live in.
since i want to get an address on my specific country (Israel)
which is not big, the idea is maybe to write a table with longitude and latitude and the main citys
and when some user use his locate button, i will find which from the table is the closest to him, and then return the data i already written in a table or something like this
so my question is:
is there a way to convert my long and latitude to the address with what i have written? or maybe is it better for me to do the second idea with prewritten data.
i don't know how to do those, so i would like to get some directions on where to start or how to look for it.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your second method, you have to use rectangular boundaries of all cities, you can search for it.
but if you want direct from long lat to location.
use google map cloud APIs, visit their website to learn more.

Comment: i dont want to use google maps because of the reason reason they want my credit card to use their api, and i dont want to put it even tho the begging is free of charge, i just dont want to get charge by an accident..
about the rectangular boundaries, i searched in google, but i dont really get something that is connected, can you give me a link perhaps?
thanks